# JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript

The following throws "JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character":

```
   var opts = "[{'UOM':'E','Description':'E - Each'},{'UOM':'C','Description':'C - Per 100'},{'UOM':'M','Description':'M - Per 1000'}]"
   var options = JSON.parse(opts);
```

What invalid character is in my JSON string? Thanks

Comment: It is not valid JSON because of the quotes http://www.json.org/ Keys and string values need to be surrounds with double quotes, not single.

Comment: Use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the apostrophes with escaped quotation marks (`\"`).